# Circle/ Ellipse geometry problem from Ramanujan

Tags: soft-question

Does someone have detail of the problem and his solution? I saw it in youtube. A rough hand sketch remade seeing YouTube video [SR geometry problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhNGCn_3hmc)  (17 min 51 sec). I have no access to the  TIFR book cited.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

The original image is here :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for edit, @Valerin

Comment: This is a part of Ramanujan's famous paper *Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$* which was published in *Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*, XLV, 1914. It is based on the approximation $\pi\approx 355/113$. Ramanujan gave another construction in same paper based on $\pi\approx (9^2+(19^2/22))^{1/4}$.

Comment: The paper of Ramanujan mentioned in last comment is available [online](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.html).

Comment: Thanks for comments @ Paramanand Singhji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

This can be found in *Mathematics Magazine*, Vol. 51, No. 3 (May, 1978), [pg 161](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689995):

> [image]

A similar sketch can be found in the *Manuscript Book 1 of Srinivasa Ramanujan*,  [pg. 54](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/nsrBook1.pdf):

> [image]

### The Problem

This can be found in the *Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society*, V, 1913, [pg 24](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram05.pdf):

> Let $PQR$ be a circle with center $O$, of which a diameter is $PR$.
> Bisect $PO$ at $H$ and let $T$ be the point of trisection of $OR$
> nearer $R$. Draw $TQ$ perpendicular to $PR$ and place the chord $RS =TQ$.
>
> Join $PS$, and draw $OM$ and $TN$ parallel to $RS$. Place a chord $PK= PM$, and draw the tangent $PL = MN$. Join $RL, RK$ and $KL$. Cut off $RC = RH$. Draw $CD$ parallel to $KL$, meeting $RL$ at $D.$
>
> [image]
>
> Then the square on $RD$ will be equal to the circle $PQR$
> approximately. For
>
> $$RS^2=\frac{5}{36}d^2,$$
>
> where $d$ is the diameter of the circle. Therefore
>
> $$PS^2=\frac{31}{36}d^2.$$
>
> But $PL$ and $PK$ are equal to $MN$ and $PN$ respectively. Therefore
>
> $$PK^2=\frac{31}{144}d^2,\quad \text{and} \quad PL^2=\frac{31}{324}d^2.$$
>
> Squaring the circle
>
> Hence
>
> $$RK^2=PR^2-PK^2=\frac{113}{114}d^2,$$
>
> and
>
> $$RL^2=PR^2+PL^2=\frac{355}{324}d^2.$$
>
> But
>
> $$\frac{RK}{RL}=\frac{RC}{RD}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{113}{355}},$$
>
> and
>
> $$RC=\frac{3}{4}d.$$
>
> Therefore
>
> $$RD=\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{\frac{355}{113}}=r\sqrt{\pi},\quad \text{very nearly}$$

Perhaps this will help you in your studies